# EditText added dynamically does not set invisble in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

I am adding some EditTexts dynamically, when a button is clicked, the  information is entered and displayed on a text View, I need to make invisible all the EditText Views, the problem that  I am facing is that only the last EditText added goes invisible. I tried to set a tag to set the EditText invisible but it is not working Am I missing something?

Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.juancho.workingout.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TEST extends Fragment {
// Add EditText Dynamically
RelativeLayout containerLayout;
static int exercisesViews = 0; // initial value
public int totalExercisesViews = 15;
Context context;

private int counterExeNumber = 1;
private int margingTopEditTextInitial = 120; // default position
private int margingTopNumberAdd = 130;

private List<EditText> editTextListName = new ArrayList<>();
EditText EditTextName;
String nameResultCardio, nameResult1, nameResult2, nameResult3;

int myTagValueCardio;
int myTagValueYesCardioExe2, myTagValueYesCardioExe3;

boolean cardioViewEnable = false;
boolean exe2IfCardioViewEnable = false;
boolean exe3IfCardioViewEnable = false;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    final View ViewCalendarEditNotesInfo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logs_add_notes, null);

    exercisesViews = 0; // Reset

    containerLayout = (RelativeLayout) ViewCalendarEditNotesInfo.findViewById(R.id.layout1);

    LogsAddNotes.isExercise1Enable = true;
    LogsAddNotes.isExercise2Enable = true;
    LogsAddNotes.isExercise3Enable = true;

    final Button btnSave = (Button) ViewCalendarEditNotesInfo.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (LogsAddNotes.isExercise1Enable == true) {

        // Set Views
        editTextName(exercisesViews);

        myTagValueCardio = (int) EditTextName.getTag();

        cardioViewEnable = true;

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (LogsAddNotes.isExercise2Enable == true) {

        exercisesViews++;
        counterExeNumber++;
        margingTopEditTextInitial = margingTopEditTextInitial + margingTopNumberAdd;

        // Set Views

        editTextName(exercisesViews);

        // Get information entered
        nameResult2 = EditTextName.getText().toString();

        myTagValueYesCardioExe2 = (int) EditTextName.getTag();

        exe2IfCardioViewEnable = true;

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (LogsAddNotes.isExercise3Enable == true) {

        exercisesViews++;
        counterExeNumber++;

        margingTopEditTextInitial = margingTopEditTextInitial + margingTopNumberAdd;

        // Set Views

        editTextName(exercisesViews);

        // Get information entered
        nameResult3 = EditTextName.getText().toString();

        myTagValueYesCardioExe3 = (int) EditTextName.getTag();

        exe3IfCardioViewEnable = true;

    }

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int index = 0;
            while (index < editTextListName.size()) {

                // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (cardioViewEnable == true && index == 0) {

                    nameResultCardio = editTextListName.get(index).getText().toString();

                    if (myTagValueCardio == index) {
                        // tToast("B1");

                        EditTextName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                }

                // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (exe2IfCardioViewEnable == true && index == 1) {

                    nameResult2 = editTextListName.get(index).getText().toString();

                    if (myTagValueYesCardioExe2 == index) {

                        // tToast("B2");

                        EditTextName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                }

                // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (exe3IfCardioViewEnable == true && index == 2) {

                    nameResult3 = editTextListName.get(index).getText().toString();

                    if (myTagValueYesCardioExe3 == index) {

                        // tToast(" B3");

                        EditTextName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                }

                // more exercises HERE

                index++;

            } // end while loop

        }// end Click

    });

    return ViewCalendarEditNotesInfo;

}// end Main

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private EditText editTextName(int _intID) {

    EditTextName = new EditText(getActivity());

    EditTextName.setId(_intID);

    EditTextName.setHint("Name");

    // CharSequence hint = "\u200F" + editText.getHint();
    // editText.setHint(hint);

    // Maximum input chars allow
    int maxLength = 10;

    // Allow only Letters
    EditTextName.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength), new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start, int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (src.equals("")) { // for backspace
                return src;
            }
            if (src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                return src;
            }
            return "";
        }
    } });

    editTextListName.add(EditTextName);
    containerLayout.addView(EditTextName);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) EditTextName.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    layoutParams.setMargins(300, margingTopEditTextInitial, 750, 0);
    // RelativeLayout.LayoutParams()
    EditTextName.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    // if you want to identify the created editTexts, set a tag, like below
    // EditTextName[i].setTag("EditText" + editText.getId());
    EditTextName.setTag(_intID);

    // tToast("THE TAG= " + _intID);

    return EditTextName;

    }

}
```

Comment: Not your problem, but you should change `EditText EditTextName;` to `EditText editTextName;` to follow convention. As it is, It makes the code more difficult to read.

Comment: You update the reference to `EditTextName` on each call to `editTextName(int)`. Find the EditText instance in your list and set its visiblity.